# Tab character in TCPDF

Tags: php, tabs, tcpdf

How do I enter TAB character befoare a paragraph. If I enter some spaces instead of TAB when I use the cell function to print some text that has two or three paragraphs justified the width of spaces before paragraphs is not the same for each paragraph and I need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I set the units of my pages to millimeters so I use css style and add "text-indent: 12.7mm;" That gets the first line to be indented the correct distance of 0.5".

Comment: This is when using writeHTML in TCPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You write \t.

It must be inside double quotes like this: "Some text \t some other text"

Comment: unfortunately this does not work atleast with the `MultiCell` method